# How do I write a better title and improve my post?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, titles

I am unable to write a proper title for my question. It is too long and I'm unable to define “non-piecewise” in my title: [Is there a non-piecewise average extending the average from Hausdorff Measure/Integral/exists for function w. domain in $\sigma$-field on C.extension?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4388729/is-there-a-non-piecewise-average-extending-the-average-from-hausdorff-measure-in)

How do I formulate a better title?

I must also note I don’t have a formal background in measure theory nor on the Hausdorff measure.

How do I make my post more clear?

Comment: The title isn't meant to fully describe the problem you want help with.  In particular you don't need to write a complete sentence.  A noun phrase is often adequate to help Readers discern whether your Question is likely to be of interest or within their expertise.  You should understand the problem well enough to follow responsive Answers, so that you will know when the solution is valid.  Use the body of the Question to setup and give the goal of your problem, and to provide *context* such as what about the problem is interesting, where it came up, or what approach or research you tried.

Comment: "[How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/282094)".